# NHibernate throwing 'could not resolve property' exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following Company with the attribute below (excluding Id):

```
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

That is mapped in a CompanyMap like this:

```
    HasOne(x => x.Category)
            .Cascade.All();
```

The Category has only the attribute:

```
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

The CategoryMap:

```
    Map(x => x.Name)
            .Column("Name")
            .Length(40)
            .Unique();
```

The table is successfully created in the DB.

I have a repository with the following queryover:

```
            var test = Session.QueryOver<Company>()
                              .WhereRestrictionOn(dbCompany => dbCompany.Category.Name)
                              .IsLike(category.Name);
```

category.name is just any string.

Then I want to access the DB and get the results with:

```
    var result = test.List();
```

I get the following exception:

```
    could not resolve property: Category.Name of: My.Name.Space.Company
```

What is wrong with the query over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the join to `Category`.

Try this:

```
Category catAlias = null;

var test = Session.QueryOver<Company>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Category, () => catAlias) // Left is optional
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => catAlias.Name)
    .IsLike(category.Name);
```